# windows file history last copied date in the future 2039-04-23 1:02AM disable file history

Tags: file-history, windows-10-pro

Folders enrolled in file history were not copied despite "run now" a couple of times.

Seemed to me the last effective run was 2021 Dec sometime.

How do I fix this?

I tried toggling file history on and off and on.

Also, I notice in the registry for file history that `ProtectedUpToTime` is 138316285449030000 in decimal or 1eb65edc4d74970 in hex; and `RestoreAllowed` is 1 while all others are 0 and (default) is not set.

Comment: On my copy of Windows 10 Pro, I see the same values as you quote, except that ProtectedUpToTime is set to 1d94dfe53bead9d. You could change your value to that and see if it starts working again as of 2023-03-04 10:05 GMT (give or take a minute or two). I suppose that a restart might be needed. Was your computer clock ever set to a date way in the future? That could explain the value you're seeing.

Comment: Using [DCode](https://www.digital-detective.net/dcode/), your `ProtectedUpToTime` is in the year 2257.  This would require a very long wait...

Comment: @AndrewMorton I tried changing the value to what you suggested but has no effect; next day I opened back-up options I see last backup:  2039-04-23 1:02 AM.

 where is that date come from? do I have to search for backup with the date and delete or remove from the appropriate history folder ?

Comment: @G.GG99 I don't want to experiment on my computer, but [How to Reset File History to Default in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/54999-reset-file-history-default-windows-10-a.html) includes a bat file which deletes `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory`. I suppose you could just rename that directory so that you can get it back if something breaks. I assume you have an actual backup on another physical drive that you can use to restore Windows and your data if it all goes horribly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all contributed. much appreciated.

Finally fixed the problem.

I looked at the registry of HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\FileHistory on a windows 11 pc that never used filehistory backup. it has only (default) value.

So I delete all non (default) values leaving subkey restorui alone.

then after I review and edit folder to backup in backup options, did a manual backup now. the last backup  time is now correct not future dated

btw: the registry now have values ProtectedUpToTime and RestoreAllowed besides (default) not set

please also note that before the mentioned steps, I tried

- setting ProtectedUpToTime to value in the past
  -disable backup and enable backup
- moving filehistory to some backup location
- recreating the folder to backup and filehistory fold location...